# What characters belong together as words in ...连日来人气火爆...?

Tags: meaning

If I knew what characters belong together, I think I can translate it adequately.

> 据了解，这些特色餐馆连日来人气火爆，前来就餐的多数是结伴而来的年轻人.
>   We understand that, day after day, many lively groups of young people come to dine.

Especially, I'm not sure about what belongs together in: 连日来人气火爆

This morning, a Chinese friend told me:

> 连日来： for a few days
>    来 works a bit like since/for
>   人气火爆： a lot of people
>   人气 works like 人们

Comment: 连日来 | 人气 | 火爆 。

Answer (score 1):

> 据了解，这些特色餐馆连日来人气火爆，前来就餐的多数是结伴而来的年轻人
>   I would break this sentence into this:
>   据/了解，这些/特色/餐馆/连日来/人气/火爆，前来/就餐/的/多数/是/结伴而来/的/年轻人

In 连日来, "连日" means "few days", with a emphasis in succession; suffix "来", short form of "以来", can be translated as "for the period of".

In "人气火爆", "人气" actually means popularity instead of people; "火爆" literally means "fire and explosion", it was usually only used to describe a living thing, or the temper thereof, meaning he/she/it has a strong temper. Nowadays, "火爆" is adopted to describe popularity too, meaning very high popularity; and for this usage, an closely related term with the same meaning being "很火", literally "very fire".

However, take note that both "人气火爆" and "很火" are somewhat slangy terms, and I would not consider them as standard Chinese.  And "很火" is usually used in mainland China and other Mandarin speaking countries. In Hong Kong, where the main spoken language is Cantonese, "很火" is not used at all.

Comment: Thanks, so we have '连日来人气火爆' is 'for a few days popular popular' ie 'very popular for a few days', they were talking about the holiday 五一。 Actually, I thought 人气 meant a person's character!

Comment: Correct. IIRC, 人氣 (人气) to mean popularity I'd borrowed from the Japanese vocabulary "人気", where the kanzi "気" comes from Chinese character "氣", however I can't find a reliable source to prove this etymology now.

Comment: And translating "人氣" literally means "human air", "human qi" or "human breath". "人氣", before being assigned the meaning of popularity and now still does, means human's qi, e.g. in somewhat archaic expressions "人氣很盛" or "人氣好盛", it means "the humans' qi is strong", implying there are many people, which in turn means high popularity.

Comment: `人氣`  indeed a borrowed Japan word(gen-ki) , that the Taiwanese medium used it for quite sometime, which then spread to Hong Kong and China.  It means `popularity`.   The typical Chinese proverb for this is `人潮汹涌`, `门庭若市`

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are obviously written by someone who speak Cantonese.

> 据了解，这些特色餐馆连日来人气火爆，前来就餐的多数是结伴而来的年轻人.

```
Cantonese/local dialect - Universal mandarin
据了解  - 　据消息来源 , 据知
特色餐馆 - 主题餐馆
连日来   - 接连几天
人气火爆 - 门庭若市，人潮汹涌， 人山人海 ，好不热闹, 生意火红
前来就餐 - 前来用餐
```

For language learner, be careful when choosing the material. Sometime, localised vocab doesn't "click" very well with typical vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

连日来 means it's been a while/a couple days.
人气火爆 means it's very popular. 
So 连日来人气火爆 is for it's been popular for a couple of days.